# How do I access API data in my HTML in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to access the API data inside my html code but I could not instead this error message keep showing.

This is the error

> message: App.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: data.map is not a function

Here is the code snippet of the data fetching

```
export async function getUsers () {

try {

    const response = await fetch('https://cornie-assessment.herokuapp.com/users/8wdkcw05bdEa47R')
    return response.json()

} catch (err) {

    console.log(err);
}
```

}

Then I imported it to my app.js file. Here is also the code

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import {getUsers} from './Components/Request'

function App() {

  const[data, setData] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {

    getUsers().then(data => {

      setData(data)

      console.log(data)
    })
  }, [])
  
  return (

    <div className="App">

      {

        data.map(items => (

          <article>{items.data.email}</article>

        ))

      }

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Whatever the data variable type is - it does not support calling map on it

Comment: If there’s an error, there’s a chance that you are returning undefined

Comment: What does your console.log actually print out? Looking at the error, you're not actually saving an object to `data` that allows for the map method

Comment: Your `getUsers()` function returns the entire response, not only `data` therefore you should change `setData(data)` to `setData(data.data)`. Furthermore items inside `data` do not have a `data` sub-key: `items.data.email` will give another error and should be changed to `items.email`

Comment: My console printed out the API data. Please can you help correct the error?

Answer (score 2):

Please check your API response and the data which you're setting to state.

`map` function work on an array.

As I have seen your API response -> It's an object type.

{"status": true, "data": [...], ...}

So, you should set the state like the below.

```
getUsers().then(res => {

  setData(res.data) // it will be an array

  console.log(res) // it's an object
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response is an object { status : true, data: [...] }. You are using an array method ( map ) on the object. Try this

```
 getUsers().then(response => {

  setData(response.data)

 })
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

problem is related assigning the response data as array

```
export async function getUsers () {

try {

    const response = await fetch('https://cornie-assessment.herokuapp.com/users/8wdkcw05bdEa47R')
   const result = await response.json()
   return result.data; // now you have an array of objects
} catch (err) {

    console.log(err);
}
```